# Blade Foreach and if statements, 2nd itteration returns true for 9 == 2

Tags: laravel, if-statement, foreach, laravel-blade

I am working on a Laravel PHP application for digital signatures,

currently in one of my blade files i have a foreach that is designed to add all the documents one at a time (on there own blade file)

however I have an issue where after the first iteration of my loop, my if statements designed to filter out only documents where the signer is defined (so that users who don't have to sign, don't see documents) are returning true for things such as ($document->responsible_signer == $user->id && $document->packet->live) where $document->responsible_signer == 9 and $user->id == 2

it works fine on the 1st iteration, but not the second.

I have simplified the code to reduce it's complexity and tried moving around which fields get called first with no change in the results, indicating it happens after the 1st iteration and not as a result of the if statements being funky

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    @foreach($facilityDocs->where('completed_at', null) as $document)
        @if($document->user_id == $user->id && $document->packet->live)
            <div class="col-4 my-3">
                @include('patient._document_card', ['document' => $document])
            </div>
        @endif
        @if($document->responsible_signer == $user->id && $document->packet->live)
            <div class="col-4 my-3">
                @include('patient._document_card', ['document' => $document])
            </div>
        @endif
        @if($document->responsible_two_signer == $user->id && $document->packet->live)
            <div class="col-4 my-3">
                @include('patient._document_card', ['document' => $document])
            </div>
        @endif
        @if($document->witness_signer == $user->id && $document->packet->live)
            <div class="col-4 my-3">
                @include('patient._document_card', ['document' => $document])
            </div>
        @endif
        @if($document->community_signer == $user->current_facility_id && $document->packet->live)
            <div class="col-4 my-3">
                @include('patient._document_card', ['document' => $document])
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

the expected result is to show only documents where as an example

$document->witness_signer == $user->id

if this is true, it returns the document, otherwise  it doesn't

here is a dump, the first document in the collection has info set, the 2nd one doesnt, both are displayed, but the 1st one is displayed twice

```
    Collection {#425 ▼
  #items: array:14 [▼
    0 => Document {#391 ▶}
    1 => Document {#392 ▶}
    2 => Document {#393 ▶}
    3 => Document {#394 ▶}
    4 => Document {#395 ▶}
    5 => Document {#396 ▶}
    6 => Document {#397 ▶}
    7 => Document {#398 ▶}
    8 => Document {#399 ▶}
    9 => Document {#400 ▼
      #dates: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "documents"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:22 [▼
        "id" => 10
        "user_id" => 1
        "visit_id" => 1
        "packet_id" => 17
        "completed_at" => null
        "created_at" => "2019-07-19 17:55:32"
        "updated_at" => "2019-07-19 17:56:29"
        "completed_by_patient" => 1
        "completed_by_responsible" => 0
        "completed_by_witness" => 0
        "completed_by_community" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible_two" => 0
        "completed_by_patient_id" => 1
        "completed_by_responsible_id" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible_two_id" => 0
        "completed_by_witness_id" => 0
        "completed_by_community_id" => 0
        "facility_id" => 1
        "responsible_signer" => 2
        "responsible_two_signer" => 9
        "witness_signer" => 10
        "community_signer" => null
      ]
      #original: array:22 [▼
        "id" => 10
        "user_id" => 1
        "visit_id" => 1
        "packet_id" => 17
        "completed_at" => null
        "created_at" => "2019-07-19 17:55:32"
        "updated_at" => "2019-07-19 17:56:29"
        "completed_by_patient" => 1
        "completed_by_responsible" => 0
        "completed_by_witness" => 0
        "completed_by_community" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible_two" => 0
        "completed_by_patient_id" => 1
        "completed_by_responsible_id" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible_two_id" => 0
        "completed_by_witness_id" => 0
        "completed_by_community_id" => 0
        "facility_id" => 1
        "responsible_signer" => 2
        "responsible_two_signer" => 9
        "witness_signer" => 10
        "community_signer" => null
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    10 => Document {#401 ▶}
    11 => Document {#402 ▶}
    12 => Document {#403 ▶}
    13 => Document {#404 ▼
      #dates: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "documents"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:22 [▼
        "id" => 14
        "user_id" => 1
        "visit_id" => 1
        "packet_id" => 21
        "completed_at" => null
        "created_at" => "2019-07-19 18:05:17"
        "updated_at" => "2019-07-19 18:05:17"
        "completed_by_patient" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible" => 0
        "completed_by_witness" => 0
        "completed_by_community" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible_two" => 0
        "completed_by_patient_id" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible_id" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible_two_id" => 0
        "completed_by_witness_id" => 0
        "completed_by_community_id" => 0
        "facility_id" => 1
        "responsible_signer" => null
        "responsible_two_signer" => null
        "witness_signer" => null
        "community_signer" => null
      ]
      #original: array:22 [▼
        "id" => 14
        "user_id" => 1
        "visit_id" => 1
        "packet_id" => 21
        "completed_at" => null
        "created_at" => "2019-07-19 18:05:17"
        "updated_at" => "2019-07-19 18:05:17"
        "completed_by_patient" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible" => 0
        "completed_by_witness" => 0
        "completed_by_community" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible_two" => 0
        "completed_by_patient_id" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible_id" => 0
        "completed_by_responsible_two_id" => 0
        "completed_by_witness_id" => 0
        "completed_by_community_id" => 0
        "facility_id" => 1
        "responsible_signer" => null
        "responsible_two_signer" => null
        "witness_signer" => null
        "community_signer" => null
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

here is part of my controller that generates the documents

```
$patient = User::where('id', $userID)->first();

// A collection of documents that belong to the users current facility
        $currentFacilityDocs = $patient->documents->filter(function($document) use ($patient) {
            return $document->visit->facility == $patient->currentFacility;
        });

        // A collection of documents that have not been marked as complete
        $unsignedDocuments = $patient->documents->filter(function($document) {
            return $document->completed_at === null;
        });

        // A collection of documents that are complete.
        $completedDocuments = $patient->documents->filter(function($document) {
            return $document->completed_at !== null;
        });

        // To print it all on the screen for testing
        // dump(['unsignedDocuments' => $unsignedDocuments], $completedDocuments, $currentFacilityDocs);


        return view('patient.dashboard')
        ->withUser($patient)
        ->withFacilityDocs($currentFacilityDocs);
    }
```

Comment: can you dd($facilityDocs->where('completed_at', null)), then put it in pastebin, 
make sure you remove if there's some important information contained there , then update your question

Comment: Never put so much Logic in your views, you should do the query with where clause in a Controller and just pass it to your view. I think it doesnt work on your Second Iteration because the query always returns the same value and always starts with the Same value

Comment: updated,

the query returns a collection, and it iterates through the collection, so the query should always be the same

Comment: Yes but it always returns the Same Collection because of the where clause it always query the collection new after Same iteration and you only access the First Element

Comment: except the query is in the foreach, and it sets it as documents so it should step through them and should never return the same iteration

if in the for each it is running the query over and over then it is not functiong properly as a for each

anyways i also updated my question with code from my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved

the problem was here

```
@if($document->community_signer == $user->current_facility_id && $document->packet->live)
```

it was changed to

```
@if($document->community_signer === $user->id && $document->packet->live === 1)
```